# How to remove the outline mat-form-filed border corner radius

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

I am using the angular material outline mat-form-field to design a form. 
I am getting the default mat-form-field outline text-box view with a border corner radius. Is there any way to remove the border corner radius of the outline mat-form-field and convert into a square text box view.

I tried to change the default styles of the angular material mat-form-field with the following, but it's not working.

//css

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start 
.alignment{
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

//html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [hideRequiredMarker]="true" 
class="alignment">
<mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>
<input type="text" matInput placeholder="Enter email address">
</mat-form-field>
```

I expect the outline mat-form-field with no border corner radius text box just like a square text box mat-form-field, but getting the default outline mat-form-field view.

Answer (score 9):

Material v7.3.4

```
.mat-form-field-outline-start, .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: this is affecting my other components with NGdeep, any way to conduct this without ng deep?

Comment: to affect only one field, you can use it inside a class.
. my-class {
.mat-form-field-outline-start, .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
}
something like this

Comment: There is a better solution not using !important. See this link, #3 "Overwriting AM styles in separate global styles — not scoped!" https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962

Answer (score 6):

This will remove the border-radius

```
.alignment .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.alignment .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

but you'll need to put it in your top-level stylesheet (e.g. styles.css), the one that is added in angular.json, in order to override the Angular Material component styling.

Answer (score 5):

This is how i removed border radius.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me when using Angular 8.1

Comment: avoid using ::ng-deep (deprecated) and avoid using !important -- these are not good practices. The solution from jinavar1 is preferred.

Comment: @TomRoggero there is no proper alternative to ng-deep... and !important is just for specificity, you cant classify is as good/bad practices

Comment: This worked for me without using !important

Answer (score 3):

My solution was very similar to other answers but I really don't like using `!important`, so I did the following (Material 9.1.0):

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove boder and add box-shadow :

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    border: none;
    border-left: none;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
    border-radius: 1px !important;
    border: none;
    border-right: none;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
    border-radius: 1px !important;
    border-bottom: none;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 20px #fff, 5px 5px 20px #babecc;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular `mat-card` remove  border-radius like this  add this in your css

```
 mat-card{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    }
```

*you can also add class and then style that class*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code and it worked for me:

```
::ng-deep  .no-line .mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular v15 and Material v15. To remove the radius for outlined input:

```
 .mdc-text-field--outlined
   .mdc-notched-outline
   .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
   border-radius: 0;
 }

 .mdc-text-field--outlined
    .mdc-notched-outline
    .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-radius: 0;
 }
```