# Change (Increase) Border Radius of Mat-Form-Field

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm working in an Angular Project using Material.

I have some mat-form-fields with inputs with the outline appearance. I'd like to change the border radius of the outline (increase it).

I read over this stackoverflow: [How to remove the outline mat-form-filed border corner radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53907313/how-to-remove-the-outline-mat-form-field-border-corner-radius) .

But none of those solutions are allowing me to increase the border correctly.
It get's close, but it causes a weird thing on the left side of the input:
[image]

I do not want to use encapsulation. I'm fine with using `::ng-deep`.

Here's a stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-pp4349?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## For Angular Material >= 16

All you need to do is override a css variable `--mdc-outlined-text-field-container-shape`.

Inside a global stylesheet included **after** your Material theme:

```css
.mdc-text-field--outlined {
  --mdc-outlined-text-field-container-shape: 28px !important;
}
```

Or directly inside a component style:

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--outlined {
  --mdc-outlined-text-field-container-shape: 28px;
}
```

## For Angular Material <= 15

You need to increase the min-width of the left and right outline and apply a proper border radius to both sides.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 28px 0 0 28px !important;
  min-width: 28px !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 28px 28px 0 !important;
  min-width: 28px !important;
}

/* Add padding to move the label and input into the center to prevent overlapping the rounded border */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
  padding: 0 32px !important;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-yjtz7l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

---

### Disclaimer

> Angular strongly discourages, and does not directly support, overriding component CSS outside the theming APIs described above. Component DOM structure and CSS classes are considered private implementation details that may change at any time.

From https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#style-customization-outside-the-theming-system

Comment: There is a better solution. See this link, #3 "Overwriting AM styles in separate global styles — not scoped!" https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962

Comment: To we aware, this will break the label overflow effect

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet I edited with a fix for the right border when the label overflow. The min-width has to be applied to both sides to prevent this.

Comment: This not work in Angular 16

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 I updated the answer for Angular Material 16.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on Angular 15, and the only solution I could find is the following:

```css
.mdc-text-field--outlined .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-radius: 0 var(--mdc-shape-small, 12px) var(--mdc-shape-small, 12px) 0 !important;
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
    border-radius: var(--mdc-shape-small, 12px) 0 0 var(--mdc-shape-small, 12px) !important;
}
```